# Categories of graded objects: terminology

Tags: category-theory, terminology

I have a terminology question. Consider graded objects of some sort; if you want to be concrete, you could consider $\mathbb{Z}$-graded vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}_2$. Some people would say that "the category of graded objects" consists of these objects along with degree-preserving maps between them: graded maps of degree 0. Others would say that the category should allow homogeneous maps of any degree.

In other words, there are two different categories, each of which is called "the category of graded objects," depending on who you talk to. Are there names that distinguish between these two categories?

By the way, I am not trying to start a discussion about who is "right" in their use of the phrase "the category of graded objects." Both meanings are in use; I am instead looking for alternate names for either or both of the categories that can help to distinguish them.

Edit: there are other variations, and it would be nice to have names for them, too. What are the objects in the category of graded vector spaces? Are they direct sums indexed by (say) the integers, or are they families of vector spaces indexed by the integers, à la Milnor-Moore? The key question is not which of these is right, but rather: are there standard names to distinguish the categories formed using these different objects? So we have options:

1. a graded vector space could be a family $\{V_\alpha\}$ of vector spaces, or
2. a graded vector space could be a direct sum $\bigoplus_\alpha V_\alpha$ of vector spaces.

And then

3. a morphism could be required to be degree-preserving, or
4. a morphism must just be homogeneous but of any degree.

Is there terminology that captures the four combinations, or at least some of them?